# How to distribute payloads in truck from a queue?

Tags: algorithm

i have been asked this interview question in one of the product base companies and i am unable to get the best way to do the same and i am really curious to know the answer.

**I have a queue from which payloads are coming , eg -  [10,20,30,40,50,60,70] , now i want to distribute these payloads into 3 trucks(or n trucks) , such that each truck carries (almost)equal weight, what is the best possible way to do the same**.

> > Please note that its a queue ,any amount of elements could be there in the queue , we only know that trucks can handle it .
> >
> > we can only see the top element in the queue , as its FIFO .

**possible solutions** :- 
1. you can average them out and keep you payloads near the average weight , which will not be a good solution as told by interviewer

Comment: I wonder if it has efficient algorithm given that partition problem is np hard. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem

Comment: Insufficient information to recommend an algorithm.  Most notably, what do you know about the queue?  How far forward can you see, and what do you know about the unseen items?  If you have total knowledge to the end of the queue, with no further additions, then the "queue" concept is bogus; you have a simple collection of weights, with the order being immaterial.

Comment: What is your metric of how uneven they are?  The gap from smallest to biggest?  The average difference from average?  The variance? When you are filling the trucks, can you switch back and forth, or is it some chunk to the first, some chunk to the second, and so on?

Comment: @PetarPetrovic If the trucks are filled in turn, it will have a polynomial solution.  If each payload can go into a different truck, then it has a pseudo-polynomial solution.

Comment: @prune : packets are coming from the queue so there is no fixed length of the queue , you have to distribute them accordingly .

Comment: @btilly: gap between smallest and largest is also not fixed , you cannot switch back and forth , as the item came out of queue you need to put it in some truck , you cannot switch back and forth either .

Comment: @Ashish168: I'm not worried whether the queue has a given length; I'm asking how far into the queue we can see.  Do we know the length?  What can we see of the payload amounts?

Comment: @Ashish168: btilly asked you to specify the metric, suggesting the maximum gap as one such metric.  You answered a different question.

Comment: Also, when you have clarifications for the problem, please edit them into your question; don't just leave them in comments, as many people won't look at the fine print.  :-)

Comment: @Prune I asked two questions.  I got one answered.

Comment: @prune : its a queue , assume we can see only one element.

Comment: We're still waiting for the metric of "best".

Comment: i don't know -  what do you mean by - metric of best ... ? please explain...

Comment: also just so you know , question was asked in final round in amazon and got rejected on this one :-(

Comment: You want "almost equal weight" and the "best possible way".  We need the metric that evaluates a solution.

Comment: Also, I want to clarify what we know about the queue: all we know is whether there are payloads remaining, and the weight of the payload at the front of the queue -- and that's *all* we know.

Comment: please note that it was asked in interview , i do not have all the answers , what i know i have told ....

Answer (score 0):

We still do not know the full problem, but I am pretty sure that it has a polynomial time dynamic programming solution.

My understanding is that we have a queue of `m` items that we are going to fill up `n` trucks with.  Each truck in turn backs up to the queue, gets loaded with a block of items, and then drives off.  We know the whole queue of available items.  We want the trucks to be "as even as possible".  For the sake of argument let's say that we want to minimize the sum of squares of differences between the theoretical average and how much each truck has.

What we need to do is create, for each item `i` in `1..m` and each `k` in `1..n` the minimum sum of squares of difference between actual trucks and the theoretical answer if we just finished filling `k` trucks.  This is a `O(nm)` data structure, and filling in each value is `O(m)` work for a total of `O(nm^2)`.

(Seek to minimize a different metric and you can get a larger polynomial.  Some metrics allow faster solutions than this one.)